# Webform get values with HtmlMail module

Tags: webforms

I'm new in Drupal7, I created a webform using webform module and I created a template for my customised html e-mail with HTMLMail module that will be sent on webform submission.
I want to put every value from the webform on a table but I don't know how to get the values entered in the webform on submission?
For example I want a result e-mail like this

```
Hello, Thank you for your registration

Name:          "webform_name_field"

Last Name :    "webform_lastname_field"

Adress :       "webform_adress_field"
```

How can I get every value of my webform ??

Comment: So how to put that code in my htmlmail.tpl.php file ??

Comment: I have to do <? print [submission:values:name:nolabel] ?> ? That doesn't work

Comment: Have you read this documentation on creating tpl files for your emails? https://www.drupal.org/node/1337488